# Port opened for Curl from ssh but not from PHP

Tags: php, curl, ssh, hosting, web-hosting

So the website is hosted on Hostgator shared server, I've chatted with the support several times now to have port 8082 opened. They have sent me a copy/paste of curl being run on SSH using that port and that it worked fine. However for my PHP script it is remaining closed.

Is there something I can do about it or something they can that they don't realize. Their advice was look for help from professional web developer. Being one, I don't have any idea what could the next step be.

I have minimized the CURL script to bare basics just so that I can get some kind of feedback from it but the error remains: "couldn't connect to host"

Comment: Are you try echo phpinfo() and find cURL is enabled or not?

Comment: cURL is enabled, I can access websites using it on port 80 and 8080 but not on 8082. While the HostGator staff claims they can do it when using cURL from SSH.